# How to paginate with act_as_api rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Hi I'm using act_as_api to render my xml and json, all is well until i want to add the will_paginate fields into my outputs.

Has anyone been successful?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in one of the feature requests for acts_as_api gem

```
    format.xml  { render_for_api :template, 
                 :xml => @posts ,
                 :root => :posts, 
                 :meta => {:current_page => @posts.current_page,
                           :total_pages => @posts.total_pages, 
                           :per_page => @posts.per_page }}
```

So there you have it, with meta support, you can add whatever you want, in this case I wanted my pagination data in there.

[Metadata support - Add pagination fields](https://github.com/coneybeare/acts_as_api/commit/b4decdf386c5727f20a9c844307565e21034f125)

Answer (score 0):

as of today, there is a wiki entry about this topic on github:

https://github.com/fabrik42/acts_as_api/wiki/Add-meta-data-%28like-pagination-info%29-to-your-response